# Assign a VLAN directly to a physical interface

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, vlan, proxmox

does anyone have an idea how to assign a VLAN ID to a physical interface under Linux?

More specifically I have a proxmox server on which Opnsense is virtualized. There are VLANs set up and on a connected switch I can assign them to the different ports.

But I would also like to use the ports directly on the server, that is I want to connect a PC to an interface and this should get a VLAN ID.

Thanks for food for thought :)

Comment: Is the physical interface already part of a bridge? If so, does Proxmox support "bridge VLAN filtering" that Linux has? (That would allow configuring PVIDs and such exactly like on a switch.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a physical interface on a VM this can be achieved via [PCI-passtrough](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/PCI(e)_Passthrough) and, if the NIC supports it, using also [SR-IOV](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/enabling-sr-iov-for-intel-nic-x550-t2-on-proxmox-6.56677/) and attach a [PF](https://libvirt.org/drvnodedev.html#sr-iov-capability) (SR-IOV physical function) to the VM.

In general it is more secure to present different interfaces for each VLAN to a VM. But in your case you can use also [Guest configured VLAN](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#_vlan_802_1q)

> Guest configured VLAN: VLANs are assigned inside the guest. In this case, the setup is completely done inside the guest and can not be influenced from the outside. The benefit is that you can use more than one VLAN on a single virtual NIC.